# Can't import classes from local files in Python

Tags: python, import, module

Python local import from files stored in at the same level of directory is often confusing to me. I have the following directory structure,

```
/distrib
  __init__.py # empty
  bases.py # contains classes MainBase etc.
  extension.py  # contains classes MainExtension etc
/errors
  __init__.py
  base_error.py
```

In file `bases.py` importing classes from `extension.py` is successful. For example, simply using `from .extensions import MainExtension` would work. On the other hand, in `extensions.py`, importing a class from `bases.py` faces challenges.

**Attempt 1**

If I `from bases import MainBase`, it complains `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bases'`.

**Attempt 2**

If I specify it as local import by `from .bases import MainBase`,  it complains `ImportError: cannot import name 'MainBase'`.

**Attempt 3**

If I import it using `from . import bases`, there is no error. But, consequently using `bases.MainBase` triggers error `module distrib.bases has no attribute 'MainBase'` and
it seem that all classes defined in the `bases.py` file are 'missing'.

However, in a different folder such as `errors`, I can import classes from `distrib.bases` normally. What exactly is happening here? Doesn't Python allow cyclical import?

Comment: If you're trying to import * from .bases it work?

Comment: @ Tom Danilov Yes, there is no error. But, the classes in ``bases.py`` are not visible at all. If I instantiate for example ``MainBase`` it complains ``NameError: name 'MainBase' is not defined``

Comment: Python does *allow* circular imports, and support for circular *relative* imports has been gradually improved over several versions.  That doesn’t allow time travel, though: your lines of code still have to execute in some order, including the ones which *create* classes and functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding python's import \* mechanics under circular reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551513/understanding-pythons-import-mechanics-under-circular-reference)

Answer (score 2):

You have a circular import. In your base module you try to import from extension. But from extension you import base. But base is not finished importing yet so that results in an ImportError when you try to import anything from the extensions module.